# How to draw parallel lines along a path in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path

I want to add border around a line. And I am trying to draw two lines along the exist one(or any other method). To achieve it. I have tried to draw two lines with different thickness. But I want a flexible method.

And I also tried to use a DrawingBrush, But the rotation and scale is a problem.

The simple code looks like this. But I want to know that is there any other convenient method to add border for a path line. Besides the start and end point of the line is not arounded by the "border" in this method.

```
<Path
    StrokeThickness="3"
    StrokeDashCap="Round"
    Stroke="Black"
    Data="{Binding PathGeometry}"
>
</Path>
<Path
    StrokeThickness="8"
    StrokeDashCap="Round"
    Stroke="{Binding Brush}"
    Data="{Binding PathGeometry}"
>
</Path>
```

It may looks like this(I need only three lines):
[image]

Comment: code code code. What are you doing in your draw code?

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian I added the code. But I want to know that is there any other better method? Or how to improve it. Thanks.  Oh, and, the picture is not generated by my code.

Comment: What exactly is a "flexible method" or a "convenient method"? Drawing a thinner line on top of a thicker line is the common way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Clemens Could I draw this using Border or DrawingBrush? What if I need more than three lines alone a path(like the picture)?

Comment: A Border is rectangular, a Brush would have to be aligned (e.g. rotated) with every line segment. If you need more lines, draw more lines on top of each other. Of course that will always result in an odd number of visible lines.

Comment: @Clemens OK..I just think drawing the override line is wasted. And this function seems useful. So I thought WPF may have the exact method to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector vLine = ( p1 - p0 ).Normalized();
Vector vPerp = new Vector( -vLine.Y, vLine.X );
Point newp0 = p0 + vPerp * offset distance
Point newp1 = p1 + vPerp * offset distance
DrawLine( newp0, newp1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the equation of line y=mx+c

```
   private Point GetParellelPoint(Point point1,Point point2,double?X,double?Y)
    {
        double slope =( point1.Y- point2.Y ) / ( point1.X- point2.X ) ;
        if(!X.HasValue)
        {
            X = (Y.Value - point1.Y) / slop + point1.X;
        }
        if (!Y.HasValue)
        {
            Y = slop*(X.Value - point1.X)   + point1.Y;
        }
        return new Point(X.Value, Y.Value);
    }
```

Point 1 and point2 is the two points of a existing line, then provide y or x based on your needs